# Describing a 'waiting' step on gherkin language

Tags: bdd, gherkin

I'm trying to describe a scenario of my app on gherkin language so that I can use it as executable spec. The scenario is more less the following: There's a phase of a process in which a check is performed. If all conditions for the check are fulfilled then the process end. Otherwise, the process waits for any condition to change (it's notified about this) and the checks again, finishing if succesful. What I'm having trouble describin is this waiting part. My current version (simplified) is:

```
Given condition A 
And not condition B
When the check is performed
Then the result is negative, pending condition B
```

What I'm trying to express with `pending condition B` is that the test will be repeated once condition B changes, but I don't particularly like this version, since it's hard to turn one to one to a test (the fact that `condition B` changes would be a new `When`).

Can anybody with more experience come up with a better formulation?

Answer (score 0):

You can either link the two tests together, like this:

```
Scenario: When A and not B result is negative, but if B happens then result is positive
  Given condition A 
  But not condition B
  Then the check returns negative
  But if condition B
  Then the check returns positive
```

Which might not be best practice but is sometimes the pragmatic way of doing things, especially if the tests are slow running because of the system under test or your test environment etc.

Or you could make it into two scenarios with some repetition behind the scenes.

```
Scenario: When A and not B the result is negative
  Given condition A 
  But not condition B
  Then the check returns negative

Scenario: When A and B the result should be positive
  Given the system has condition A but not B
  And the check is returning negative
  When condition B
  Then the check returns positive
```

In your case I would say that which one to choose depends on how long your tests take to run.  If they are slow then go for one big scenario.  If they aren't, or it doesn't matter for some reason then go for the second suggestion.  The second suggestion will give more information about the cause of the failure which is nice to have, but if the tests are slow then I think it would still be quite obvious why the the test was failing even if you are using one big scenario.